# a worker gets salary, interns get what?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

An employee or salaried person gets **salary**, consultants get their **consultancy fees**. Interns get what? If they are paid, what term is used? This is in respect of software-engineering/coding to make it in plain English.

Comment: As it is currently asked, this appears not to be a question about learning the English Language. Consider asking on http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ or see https://www.looksharp.com/guides/how-to-add-interns-to-payroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salaried workers work for a *salary*, hourly workers work for a *wage*, consultants work for a *fee* (or at a *contract rate*), and interns work *for the experience* (if they are unpaid).  If they are paid a wage, then in some places, by law, they cannot be considered "interns" but are "hourly employees".

In some situations an intern might be paid a [*stipend*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stipend), which amounts to a flat rate per hour, week, month, or for the duration of their employment, to help cover their expenses.

Comment: Off topic note: I wrote that interns get "fuck all" (BrE) or "jack shit" (AmE) -- two vulgar ways to say they get "next to nothing".  All too often these days an "intern" is hired to replace a paid employee, working a regular job for no money in order to "get experience".  This kind of exploitation is against the law in many places, but nevertheless the interns can't complain because they might forever be blacklisted from their chosen profession.  See for example [this article](http://deadline.com/2015/07/black-swan-interns-lawsuit-overturned-1201467302/) on the practice in the film industry.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. A salary is when someone is guaranteed a pre-determined amount of pay which is given to them at set intervals (e.g. a paycheck every 2 weeks).

Some interns are salaried. Some interns are unpaid.

It is fairly typical though, for interns to be compensated based on the number of hours they have worked in a given period. When someone's pay is per-hour, but not on a consulting basis, that pay is usually called "wages".

So an intern earns an "hourly wage" if they are paid a certain amount per hour they have worked.